# Algebra Inequality Proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $a, b, c, d$ be positive numbers. Prove that $\frac{a+b+c+d}{4} \ge \sqrt{\frac{ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd}{6}}$.

I was told to rewrite the sum on the right side in terms of $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2$ and $a + b + c + d$ but I am unsure how to combine the terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$(a+b+c+d)^2=(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)+2(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd)$$

Let

$$A=a+b+c+d$$
$$B=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$$

Now, this amounts to prove,

$$\frac{A^2}{16} \geq \frac{A^2-B}{12}$$

$$4B \geq A^2$$

You can also write it

$$ \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2} \geq \frac{a+b+c+d}{2}$$

Or

$$ \sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}{4}} \geq \frac{a+b+c+d}{4}$$

And you should recognize this as a standard inequality between quadratic and arithmetic mean. You can prove it using [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality), which states that

$$\left| \sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i \right| \leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2}$$

With $b_i=1$ and $a_i \geq 0$, you get

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2} \sqrt{n}$$

Or

$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2}$$

---

In case you don't know Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, here is a standard proof.

The following inequality is obviously true because it's a sum of squares:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (a_i - \lambda b_i)^2 \geq 0$$

Now, develop w.r.t. $\lambda$, to get

$$ \left(\sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2\right) \lambda^2 - 2 \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i\right) \lambda + \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2\right) \geq 0$$

It's a positive trinomial (in $\lambda$), thus its [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) must be $\leq 0$ (otherwise there would be two roots, and it would becom negative between them, which is not possible).

Write the inequality on the discriminant:

$$4 \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i\right)^2 - 4\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2\right) \leq 0$$

And finally,

$$ \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i\right)^2 \leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2\right)$$

Or

$$\left| \sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i \right| \leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2}$$

Answer (score 5):

another approach is: square both sides and rearrange, we have:

$\iff3(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)\ge 2(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd)$

with $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge ab+bc+ac$ <1>
we also have:   $a^2+b^2+d^2\ge ab+bd+ad$<2> and $a^2+c^2+d^2\ge ad+cd+ac$<3>

edit: $b^2+c^2+d^2\ge bc+bd+cd$ <4>

<1>+<2>+<3>+<4> $\implies 3(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)\ge 2(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd)$